# Fullpage.js custom navigation indicators shifting color randomly in Safari

Tags: jquery, css, safari, fullpage.js

I'm building a site that uses fullpage.js. On this site i use `navigation: true` to get my navigation indicators when the users scrolls up and down.

Then i customize the navigators in my css with the colors `background: rgb(255,162,39);` and `background: rgb(147,102,247);`. Everything works the way i want it to. But in Safari on desktop, the bullets turn blue as soon as you start to scroll or hover over them.

If i change the colors i get other weird colors shifting going on. But if i have them black and white its all fine. I tried to build my own navigators, and not use the `fullpage.js` built in navigators. But i get the same color glitch on them, in Safari, and only on desktop.

[image: This is what it look like:]
I have nothing blue in my code. Does anyone have an idea of what is going on here?

Comment: It is a bug in Safari. [I myself asked about it time ago.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330569/bug-in-safari-9-adding-blue-color-to-links-border)

Comment: Thanks! Do you want me to keep the question to help others that might have the same problem? Even if its already answered @Alvaro